# What are the disadvantages of client-only routes?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, gatsby

With a `gatsbyjs` site I am considering whether I serve restricted pages from the server (traditional approach I'd say) of from the client with the client-only routes concept (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-a-site-with-authentication/)

What I would like though is to have a `static url` with content that shows or not depending on the authentication status, not a different `client-only url` that only that client can access at that moment

I wonder whether this is "the" disadvantage of not having a server, or whether this is not the case and I'm not understanding it well

And, are there other / any disadvantages versus the server-based approach?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `static URL`? An URL you can type into the browser?

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant What URL could you not type in to the browser? Do you mean an app route URL vs using with no cording URL change and/or history?

Comment: @DaveNewton maybe it's clearer with my comment to Elite's answer (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with two disadvantages that are really just other ways to protect private routes:

1. Server computation
2. Supplying user specific data
3. Gatsby does not render dynamically on the server

**1. Server computation**

One disadvantage can be that the client renders the page not your server. This can also be an advantage if you want to minimize server computation. Other than that there are no disadvantages. It's just another way to protect private routes.

You can define client-only routes such as `www.your-site.com/settings/account` via the client-only mechanic described in the docs you linked. This route is protected for users that are logged in. If they are not logged in, the site will not be rendered, and they are redirected to a login page.

**2. Supplying user specific data**

I'm not sure what you mean by static URL. As long as your user is logged in, the URL `www.your-site.com/settings/account` will be rendered for them. You can supply the correct data for the user through JSON web tokens, cookies, sessions, all kinds of APIs.

This again is not a really disadvantage. For server and client rendered pages you always need to build up your APIs in a way that they send private data only to authenticated users.

**3. Gatsby does not render dynamically on the server**

Which means you will have to implement a server rendered page into a static site. I don't think there are any official documentation for this. There is no point in using Gatsby, a stic-site generator, when you render part of the site dynamically again.

If you commit to Gatsby I recommend the client-only route because then it remains a static site with all its advantages all the way.

Comment: Let's say I have posts with private and public content, with defined urls such as `www.your-site.com/posts/1' ... `www.your-site.com/posts/50' and all urls must be accessible from non-logged and logged users, but logged users will have all content. This can be done with client-only routes?

Comment: @GWorking No, it cannot. An URL `www.your-site.com/posts/50` can either be public / static or client-only. You can create a public URL `www.your-site.com/posts/50` and serve private content via an API that checks whether the user is logged in. The React App under the hood does not care if it renders public or private content. It's just data. The API must make sure if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, and then that API needs a server, so one client-only-routes's disadvantage would be that it requires entire pages to be private, you cannot build hybrid pages with private and public content there

Comment: The hybird content comes from the way the API is called: A logged in user gets private and public data because he is authenticated by methods like JWT, cookies, sessions. A non-logged in user gets only public data. That is what the A (API) in JAMstack is all about. Either way you need a backend server that checks user authentication: Render the page on the server or let a secured API call access private data and then show it on the static site. The use case for client-only routes are quite specific like private account settings or the checkout funnel of an e-commerce application.